# Teradata JDBC connection error in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, teradata, rest

I am creating springboot rest api which connect `Teradata` database but when i start the application i get below error , is there any configuration missing? here is the version of dependency i am using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
            <artifactId>tdgssconfig</artifactId>
            <version>14.00.00.13</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
            <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>14.00.00.13</version>

        </dependency>
```

application.properties changes

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:teradata://HOST/database=mydb
spring.datasource.username=MYID
spring.datasource.password=MYPW
```

ERROR

`2021-03-01 12:18:33.430  WARN 18104 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.13] [Error 165] [SQLState HY000] isValid: function not supported in this version`

Comment: From 2016 [Teradata JDBC Driver Problem](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/issues/102)

Comment: That's an extremely old version of the driver. What version is your database?

Comment: isValid method supported from v15.10 of the driver and later.

Comment: https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/general/pom-file-for-maven-project

Comment: Thanks, update to latest version of tdgssconfig and terajdbc4 fixed this issue.